# Problem with mutate when trying to create a line_id column

Tags: r, typeerror, row-number, mutate, rowid

I need to create a line ID column within a dataframe for further pre-processing steps. The code worked fine up until yesterday. Today, however I am facing the error message:
"Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `line_id = (function (x, y) ...`.
Caused by error:
! Can't convert `y`  to match type of `x` ."

Here is my code - the dataframe consists of two character columns:

```
split_text <- raw_text %>%
  mutate(text = enframe(strsplit(text, split = "\n", ))) %>%
  unnest(cols = c(text)) %>%
  unnest(cols = c(value)) %>%
  rename(text_raw = value) %>%
  select(-name) %>%
  mutate(doc_id = str_remove(doc_id, ".txt")) %>% 
  # removing empty rows + add line_id
  mutate(line_id = row_number())
```

Besides `row_number()`, I also tried `rowid_to_column`, and even `c(1:1000)` - the length of the dataframe. The error message stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly specifying the data type of the "line_id" column as an integer using the `as.integer()` function, like this:

```
mutate(line_id = as.integer(row_number()))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this leads to the same error message.

Comment: The problem has to be related to the `mutate()` function.

Comment: Can you add a sample of your data? It would be a lot helpful to deal with the error. @stacksterppr

Answer (score 0):

This code works but is not fully satisfying, since I have to break the pipe:

```
split_text$line_id <- as.integer(c(1:nrow(split_text)))
```